# Optional substring in capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that correctly captures a slash followed by a number in a string.  The capturing group portion of the regex looks like this:

```
\(\d)+\\??
```

(some digits after a slash up to, but not including, a question mark) and there is more to the regex before and after this capturing group.  Now I want to also include in my capturing group a optional specific prefix (call it "abc_"):

- The entire prefix (all four characters) must be there to be included in the captured group
- If no prefix is present then the digit portion of the capturing group is still captured
- if the prefix is partially there or some other prefix is there then the string does not match the regex.

Some examples:

```
abc_12345  is captured
12345      is captured
ab_12345   fails to match the regex
abc_       fails to match the regex
abcd_      fails to match the regex
```

How do I construct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
((?:abc_)?\\d+)[?]?
```

The ?: operator transforms the group into a non-catching group. I don't understand the part with the partial prefix. If you allow any content in front of the regex, you cannot deny a certain optional prefix. You need to have a clear separator in front of the pattern, like a white space in order to deny a prefix.

Comment: I added some examples to the question

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not even seem to work for the case you already described. It captures only one digit and not the full number. Also your escaping is inconsistent.

However, this should do what you intend to do:

```
((?:abc_)?\\d+)\\??
```

Your last requirement, that a different prefix should not be matched, can only be answered if you give use the preceding part of the regex. (If this capturing group is preceded by `\w+` for instance, any prefix would match, but only the full and correct prefix would be captured)

Comment: also showed that there is a slash before the optional prefix and digits, although the slash is not to be captured.

Comment: in this case there shouldn't be any problems. does the regex work?